# Have I had nationality since I was born or since I got my passport?

Tags: citizenship, dual-citizenship, nationality

I'm a decedent to Jewish diaspora parents who have been taken their citizenship illegally. I have now applied for citizenship and received a certificate confirming that I am a citizen, and a new passport. My question is- have I always had nationality of that country (i.e. since I was born) or have I had the nationality only since I applied for it?

For privacy reasons I didn't use my name in this post, and didn't specify the countries to which I am a citizen. I hope you understand.

Comment: Welcome to [Law.SE]!  As you may be aware, laws vary from country to country, so I highly doubt that this question can be answered definitively without knowing the countries involved.  If privacy is that big of a concern for you, this forum may not be the best place to get answers;  consulting a lawyer may be your best option.

Comment: You say "parents who have been taken their citizenship illegally". Sorry, but this is not correct English and its hard to be sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean that your parents took (i.e. gained) their citizenship illegally, or do you mean that your parents had their citizenship taken away illegally? Either way, who says it was illegal?

Comment: So which citizenship did you get? And please make clear: Was your parent's citizenship taken away from them illegally, and which one, or did your parents take on a new citizenship illegally, and which one?

Comment: Based only on the information you've provided, it could be either one.  It depends on exactly what kind of application you made, exactly what kind of certificate you received, and the precise laws of the (unidentified) country in question.  There's insufficient information here to answer your question.

Comment: I sympathize with your desire for privacy, but you have to mention the country which did the persecution and possibly also the country where your ancestors lived afterwards. Otherwise it is stumbling in the dark.

Comment: The entity that gave you your certificate is the one that would be in the best position to answer your question (in case it isn't already shown in the certificate). Also, what do you want it for? If it is for some kind of official document, depending on its own rules, you might need to put the date when your nationality was recognsed, even if you and that right since you were born.

Comment: Regarding your privacy, (a) we don't care about the name you go by on day-to-day, 'Someone' is perfectly fine; and (b) this is your only question in Stack Exchange (thus, there's no other to link you), so mentioning the countries involved shouldn't be much of an issue to your privacy. Don't feel obliged to share anything you don't feel comfortable to, but knowing some details would really help in getting an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the country in question is Germany and you recieved a **Staatsangehörigkeitsausweis** (Yellow paper): then it is from birth.

If it is a **Einbürgerungurkunde** (Green paper): then from the date of issue.